# Which deities in Hinduism could be most closely equated to Titania and Oberon (fairy king & queen)?

Tags: magic, culture, religion, mythology

I am looking to create a version of Titania & Oberon, the Queen & King of the Fairies in Midsummer Night's Dream, that would have context in India.  Probably deities or mythological beings associated with nature/forests, but maybe with a tradition of meddling with humanity?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Maxine*! While you say that you are creating your own version of something it looks like you could profit from the tips of experts on the topic of mythology, so I recommend checking out one of our sister sites: [MythologyAndFolklore.SE](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/). If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: (A little tip about the StackExchange network: cross-posting is not very well-received most of the time, because questions can and should be migrated. If you feel a question is perfectly fine on two or more sites without any changes, chances are it's off-topic on all of them instead. Taking the tour and visiting the help center on each helps to get an idea of the focus of each site. Just a tip for the future, I hope you continue contributing to the network and find the answer you are looking for.)

Answer (score 1):

Any of the Rishi (sages) were much like Titania, Oberon, or Puck. They wandered the world and, if offended, could curse or bless with mere words and immediate effect. Specifically, I'm thinking about how the Rishi cursed Pandu to not be able to have children. Pandu's wife called in a favor from another Rishi to work around the curse.

The naga king Vasuki also springs to mind - having family (a daughter, at least) and living near natural environs. His family took Bhima from the river when he had been poisoned by his cousin and cured the poison. He also gave Bhima super strength.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I'm particularly interested in the story of the changeling child that Titania abducts/adopts and that causes the argument with her husband, Oberon (in Shakespeare's a Midsummer Night's dream).  Are there any parallels in Indian mythology to this idea that you can think of?